# ReferenceError when build with grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to build kibana from source,  can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Thanks.

```
C:\workspace\kibana>grunt -v
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
...
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> ReferenceError: window is not defined
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\kibana\node_modules\load-grunt-config\node_modules\js-yaml\lib\js-yaml\type\js\function.js:17:7)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>   at require (module.js:380:17)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\kibana\node_modules\load-grunt-config\node_modules\js-yaml\lib\js-yaml\schema\default_full.js:23:5)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>   at require (module.js:380:17)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\kibana\node_modules\load-grunt-config\node_modules\js-yaml\lib\js-yaml\loader.js:8:27)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>   at require (module.js:380:17)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\kibana\node_modules\load-grunt-config\node_modules\js-yaml\lib\js-yaml.js:4:14)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>   at require (module.js:380:17)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\kibana\node_modules\load-grunt-config\node_modules\js-yaml\index.js:6:12)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>   at require (module.js:380:17)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\kibana\node_modules\load-grunt-config\lib\load-config.js:3:14)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>   at require (module.js:380:17)
>>   at Object.module.exports (C:\workspace\kibana\Gruntfile.js:75:3)
>>   at loadTask (C:\workspace\kibana\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:325:10)
>>   at Task.task.init (C:\workspace\kibana\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:437:5)
>>   at Object.grunt.tasks (C:\workspace\kibana\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt.js:120:8)
>>   at Object.module.exports [as cli] (C:\workspace\kibana\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\cli.js:38:9)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt:45:20)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>>   at startup (node.js:119:16)
>>   at node.js:906:3

No tasks specified, running default tasks.
Running tasks: default
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

**NOTE:**

I cloned kibana repo from github and did not made any change, I also checked the code in **function.js** and there is truely reference to **window**:

```
...
try {
  esprima = require('esprima');
} catch (_) {
  /*global window */
  if (window) { esprima = window.esprima; }
}
...
```

As my understanding, **window** should not exist in server side javascript, so I am wondering how can it work?

Comment: You’re right that `if (window)` doesn’t make any sense, but try `npm install esprima`. `npm install` by itself if you haven’t yet.

Comment: Did you follow [this guide](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#development-environment-setup)?

Comment: @zaynetro, I tried, but it always fails on my windows.